# How to put selenium webdriver within a Java Applet

Tags: java, python, selenium

I am using selenium to automate some tasks and attempted this with python but had no luck. From what I have been reading Java is the best way to go. I am trying to automate some tasks for myself. i want to fill out and submit forms using selenium. The form has 10 fields. All fields are automated with selenium except for 3 which i fill out. my problem is, I am able to completely fill out the fields and submit the form using java but I can't figure how to fill in the 3 fields by me (currently i open the selenium java in eclipse, change the 3 fields, compile and then run, need to do this with each new submission).

I want to create a JApplet form and enter the 3 fields, then that would put it into selenium java and submit it. I have searched all over and cant find any way to complete this task.

**Clarification**

```
**My Current Setup**
Selenium in Java (using eclipse)
Task 1:
- Fields 1 - 7 prefilled and never change.
- I change:
  - WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("Type")); element.sendKeys("XXX");
  - WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("ID")); element.sendKeys("XXX")
  - WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("Manu")); element.sendKeys("XXX");
- Compile and Run
- Selenium goes to website using driver.get("http://www.example.com");
- fills 1 - 10 and hits submit.

Task 2:
- Fields 1 - 7 prefilled and never change.
- I go back into eclipse and change:
  - WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("Type")); element.sendKeys("YYY");
  - WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("ID")); element.sendKeys("YYY")
  - WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("Manu")); element.sendKeys("YYY");
- Compile and Run
- Selenium goes to website using driver.get("http://www.example.com");
- fills 1 - 10 and hits submit.

etc....

I want to make it so I dont have go back each time and change the fields above for each new task. I want to have a web form on a web page have these three fields.

I want:
Task 1
MySite -> FORM with textbox: Type, ID, Manu -> Submit -> fills into the XXX above -> run Selenium
Task 2
MySite -> FORM with textbox: Type, ID, Manu -> Submit -> fills into the YYY above -> run Selenium
```

hope this makes sense

Comment: This needs more information, what's so special about these 3 fields? What problems have you had having Selenium fill it out for you? Show us the code that fails and the HTML of the stuff you are trying to interact with.

Comment: nothing fails. selenium is working fine. The form is basic html and i am able to fully complete the form and submit it using selenium. the three fields i add is `Type`, `ID`,`Manu`. All the other fields selenium fills out. This is basically so I dont have to fill out all the fields which is very time consuming. But i want a way to automate it to a webpage. for example I want a webpage that has `Type, ID, Manu` in a `Text` field then when I hit submit it puts those in selenium. this way i wont have to open eclipse change the 3 fields then recompile and run.

Comment: I understand now, makes a lot more sense, thank you. What do you intend to make the webpage in? Is it going to be a local website or stored on a server somewhere? What languages do you know/are comfortable with right now? Does it have to be a webpage or can it be an application? (I.e a console application that just asks for a few lines of input?) I ask, because something like a Console app is probably more easier for you to do in Java.

Answer (score 0):

I am very confused by your explanation. In your comment you stated "I want a webpage that has Type, ID, Manu in a Text field then when I hit submit it puts those in selenium". That is not the way Selenium works. Selenium can be used to take actions on your web page - the same way that a human user would interact with the web page. You don't "put things into Selenium" from your web page. It's the other way around. Selenium interacts with your web page, clicking buttons, clicking links, typing text, etc. Please clarify your question and post an example of what you are trying to do if necessary.